# Как поставить последнюю версию git?

Tags: linux, git, debian, apt-get

У меня веб-сервер на debian поставил git через apt-get install git поставилась версия 2.1.4 но на хабре была статья про версию 2.7 и в ней есть несколько интересных фишек, которые меня заинтересовали.

Как правильно обновить git на сервере до последней версии? Нужно свежие репозитории вручную добавлять? И как перед установкой узнать какая версия установится?

Comment: Ты будешь тестировать новые фичи на продакшн сервере?

Comment: @don Rumata ну я же не спрашиваю как мне не сломать что ни будь, так что не беспокойтесь об этом ))

Comment: Скачать Git из репозитория Git и собрать у себя в $HOME?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

судя по [информации о пакете *git* в разных релизах дистрибутива *debian gnu/linux*](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=git&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all), у вас стоит релиз *jessie* (доступная версия пакета: `1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u4`. символы `1:` означают «эпоху», это [«внутренняя кухня» пакетирования](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version), upstream-версия программы здесь — `2.1.4`). уточнить версию релиза можно командой:

```
$ lsb_release -rc
Release:        8.9
Codename:       jessie
```

если программа *lsb_release* отсутствует, то можно просто посмотреть файлы в `/etc` такой, например, командой (пример вывода как раз на системе с релизом *jessie*):

```
$ cat /etc/*release*
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

---

путей поставить более новую версию программы много. наименее «болезненный» — подключить репозиторий *jessie-backports* и установить имеющуюся там версию `1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1`.

согласно инструкциям с сайта [backports.debian.org](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/):

1. надо добавить описание репозитория:

   ```
   $ echo "deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian jessie-backports main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jbp.list
   ```
2. и обновить список пакетов:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```

теперь будет доступна для установки более новая версия пакета *git* (в данном случае — `1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1 0`):

```
$ apt-cache policy git
git:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u4
  Version table:
     1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1 0
        100 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
     1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u4 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u3 0
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

вот её и устанавливайте:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends -t=jessie-backports git=1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1
```

- `--no-install-recommends` — не ствить пакеты, рекомендумые в устанавливаемом пакете (на сервере имеет смысл всегда пользоваться такой опцией или даже настроить *apt* на такое *умолчальное* поведение)
- `-t=jessie-backports` — брать при необходимости пакеты из репозитория *jessie-backports*
- `git=1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1` — установить пакет *git* именно указанной версии

---

в конце концов проверяем, что же установилось:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.11.0
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно установить Git последней версии из репозитория нестабильного дистрибутива.

```
echo 'deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian unstable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unstable.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git/unstable
```

А чтобы нечайно вся система не обновилась до нестабильного состояния, создайте файл `/etc/apt/preferences.d/unstable` со следующим содержимым

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 90
Package: git
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 200
```

Кстати, обратите внимание, в последней версии Git 2.14.1 была исправлена [серьёзная уязвимость](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=150238802328673), настоятельно рекомендуется обновиться. Кроме того, у вас на сервере, судя по всему, стоит Debian Jessie, срок поддержки которого уже меньше года. Так же стоит обновить.

Comment: наверно, из backports будет всё-таки понадёжнее.

Comment: у меня в репах пока: >git --version
git version 2.14.0 - буду ждать, когда прилетит обнова)

Answer (score 2):

Последняя версия 2.14

2.14 выпущена 2017-08-04, а 2.7 зарелизили почти 2 года назад 2015-10-04

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git

Попробуйте:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y
git --version
```

Comment: Эм... 2.1.4 != 2.14

Comment: `2.7 зарелизили почти 2 года назад 2015-10-04`
да всё верно у меня просто сервер давно установлен и настроен и там в ОС старые репы и пакеты

Comment: Я случайно рано опубликовал ответ)

Comment: Боюсь, ppa это не про дебиан