# Как добавить репозиторий в /etc/apt/sources.list.d, но чтобы из репозитория обновлялся только 1 пакет?

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, apt

У меня debian 9, и у меня появилась нужда установить git версии 2.17, но в debian 9 максимальная версия в стандартном репозитории 2.11.

Чтобы обновить git до новой версии, я решил добавить репозиторий ubuntu bionic:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

И у меня все получилось! Но при написании apt update мне пишет, что доступно для upgrade 300+ пакетов. Все эти пакеты из репозитория ubuntu bionic, который я добавил для установки git. Естественно я не хочу их обновлять, ведь я сломаю систему.

Можно ли как-то в source.list файле сказать не обновлять все пакеты из репозитория, а обновлять только один пакет - git?

Comment: в stretch-backports есть версия новее — 2.20: https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/git

Comment: ну и вообще: [Как поставить последнюю версию git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/705165/178576)

Comment: вопрос заключался не в том, как обновить git. я на примере git описал вопрос

Comment: ну и мои комментарии имеют отноешение к программе git только как к примеру.

Comment: ок, благодарю. вообще мне важно было установить любую версию выше >2.12, так что я взял первый попавшийся репозиторий убунты, там было 2.17

Comment: а уж по поводу того, что смешивать репозитории *разных* дистрибутивов — это очень плохая идея, написано много где и неоднократно. например: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251239/110559), [2](https://serverfault.com/q/126920/292034) и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: я в курсе про все опасности этого подхода. но в случае с git все работает

Comment: вот в частном случае пакета с программой git и соответствующей комбинации ваших основных и конкретного «левого» репозитория вам повезло: пакет просто установился (может быть потянув пару-тройку других пакетов по зависимостям). а при иных комбинациях пакетов/репозиториев apt мог вам предложить пол-системы переустановить. upd. собственно, такую комбинацию вы и описали в вопросе: при update вам именно это и предлагается сделать — переустановить пол-системы.

Comment: не потребовалось обновлять зависимости при обновлении git с 2.11->2.17. если бы потребовалось, то я бы не рисковал таким образом делать

Comment: https://interface31.ru/tech_it/2016/03/ispolzuem-apt-pinning-dlya-zakrepleniya-paketov-v-debian-ubuntu.html